# Simplify $ \frac{b}{a-b}+ \frac{a}{b-a}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a question regarding simplification of an algebraic expression.

Here is the problem:

$ \frac{b}{ a - b} + \frac{a}{b-a}  $

The outcome is $ -1 $

Here is how I try to simplify it:

1. Add fractions: $ \frac{ b(-a+b) + a(a-b)}{(a-b)(-a+b)} $
2. FOIL: $ \frac{a^2 - 2ab + b^2}{(a-b)(-a+b)} $
3. Apply Binomial Decomposition: $ \frac{(a-b)^2}{(a-b)(-a+b)} $
4. Reduce fractions: $ \frac{\color{red}{(a-b)}(a-b)}{\color{red}{(a-b)}(-a+b)}$

The answer is: $ \frac{a-b}{-a+b} $

Now in the book the answer is, as previously mentioned is $-1$

How do I get my answer $ \frac{a-b}{-a+b} $ to become $-1$ ?

Could you, please, *explain* the steps necessary to get that answer?

Thank you

Comment: Note: $(-a+b)=-(a-b)$. This should help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've pretty much done everything. Note that $-a+b = -(a-b)$ so your expression becomes

$$\frac{a-b}{-a+b} = \frac{a-b}{-(a-b)} = -1.$$

Answer (score 4):

Notice that $-a+b=-(a-b)$. Thus: $\frac{a-b}{-a+b}=\frac{a-b}{-(a-b)}=-\frac{a-b}{a-b}=-1$.

You could also have done this in a much easier way:

$\frac{b}{a-b}+\frac{a}{b-a}=\frac{b}{a-b}-\frac{a}{-(b-a)}=\frac{b}{a-b}-\frac{a}{a-b}=\frac{b-a}{a-b}=-1$